# Почему "лишняя" точка с запятой не влияет на выполнение программы?

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

;// "лишняя" точка с запятой

int main()
{
   std::cout << 1;
}
```

Почему такой код скомпилируется? Я знаю, что в теле функции ";" является null-statement, но в данном случае эон таковым не является, т. к. за телом функции никаких statement'ов быть не может. Объясните мне пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Объявления тоже бывают пустые.

> #### [`[dcl.pre]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#1)
>
> ```
> empty-declaration:
>     ;
> ```